# OpenLayers plugin in QGIS, error in projection 3857 Pseudo Mercator

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm using QGIS plugin OpenLayers to set the background of Google satellite under my vector layer. However, even if I project my layers as EPSG:3857 (the default and only possible projection for OpenLayers) my layers do not overlap correctly.

What is strange, is that at the beginning it was working, then I saved and closed the project and now I can't overlap them correctly any more. In addition, when it was working correctly, I saved the image and in the resulting picture the layers weren't correctly overlapped...

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does it overlap (mostly) correctly east-west, and just has a north-south error?

Comment: No the error is huge and my vector layers fall out of the satellite image, However if I set a WGS84 4326, the vectors are slighly shifted est-west

Comment: Can you add the extent of the vector layer, as reported by layer Properties, Metadata tab? How did you `project the layers as EPSG:3857?`

Comment: Sure, the vector layer has this extension: xMin, yMin 13.4532,43.5112 : xMax,yMax 13.6239,43.602.  The projection is changed by right click on the layer and setting the "SR of layer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please** do **not** change the CRS of the **layers** with `Set CRS of layer`. This will make your data unusable, because it changes the CRS, but not the coordinates.

As you can read from the extent, the coordiantes are still in degrees.

So use `Set Layer CRS` once again to assign EPSG:4326 for it, then use `Save As...` with another filename, and the desired CRS.